# Is it possible to use a single TFS build definition to deploy multiple project apps into their respective deployment folders?

Tags: tfsbuild, build-definition

Our solution (the structure of which I personally don't have any control of) has an MVC web application project, and several WCF app projects. We've got our TFS server set up so that for our real time dev environment, each of those applications are deployed to their corresponding folders in the file system, which are then mapped through IIS.

This is done using individual build definitions (i.e. one build definition to deploy the MVC web app, and one build definition **each** for the WCF app deployments).

Is there a way to handle this (build, deploy to corresponding folders) using just one build definition? While our server can definitely handle it, I just can't shake off the feeling that we're being very inefficient with how we're doing it now, requesting individual builds for each application then deploying, etc etc.

Comment: Is this what you mean: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504202/problems-with-msbuild-outputpath-and-outdir-in-tfs2010 ?

Comment: That looks like a pretty big step in the right direction, yes. I'll give it a read; much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You will need to specify the arguments in the project files for deployment and leave out the parameters in the TFS build arguments