# TFS 2012 build - project specific output folder

Tags: tfsbuild

I have a Visual Studio 2012 solution with about 30 C# projects. I'm setting the Output Path in Visual Studio to put all my Plugins in a Subdirectory of my Binary Directory.

How can I put my Plugins in the ..\Binary\Plugins\ Folder with TFS 2012 Buid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with MSBuild OutputPath and OutDir in TFS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504202/problems-with-msbuild-outputpath-and-outdir-in-tfs2010)

Comment: There are some significant changes between TFS2010 and TFS2012.

Comment: There are no significant differences in MSBuild however :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will take care of it, but how ridiculous...

http://lajak.wordpress.com/2011/05/07/customize-binaries-folder-in-tfs-team-build/

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new solution just for the Plugins and build that.

TFS 2012 now comes with new build configuration option to set all solutions to output in their own directory.

- Edit your Build Configuration
- Click the `Process` tab
- Expand `Advanced`
- Set `Solution Specific Build Outputs` = `true`

Comment: But I have references from my Plugins to the other Projects in my Solutions. Are there any other Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I have now created a move task to move my plgins after the build to the Plugins directory by calling the System.IO.File.Move Method. It's not a very nice solution but it works.