# How do you get Visual Studio to write build output to a single directory?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, build

In a TFS build, all build outputs are written to a single directory; this behaviour achieved by passing msbuild an /p:OutDir switch. Is there a way I can pass this property in Visual Studio to apply a single output directory to all projects in one solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with MSBuild OutputPath and OutDir in TFS2010](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504202/problems-with-msbuild-outputpath-and-outdir-in-tfs2010)

Comment: I've just had a look at your suggested duplicate and I don't think it is the same. I require a way to mimic the default TFS output behaviour in the Visual Studio IDE on a developer machine. The other question is trying to make the TFS machine behave like their development machines.

Comment: Sorry, I re-read your question and I see what you mean.

Comment: No problem Dave, thanks for taking the time.

Comment: One solution to this problem is to set every project file (in all configurations) to build to the same path. That's what we do - hence how I ended up with that problem.

Comment: Yeah, that would achieve what I'm after, but I ideally wanted some way of applying it in one place. Seems a bit weird you can't do certain things from inside Visual Studio but you can with msbuild!

Comment: That's pretty much it, either MSBuild scripts or per project.