# TFS 2012 build copy console application to _PublishedWebsites

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using TFS 2012 build option to build my web application. I have couple of console application in the solution. I want the console application output to be copied to the bin folder. In visual studio, I am doing this by using the copy command in the Post build event command option. But this does not work in TFS builds. The generated exe is not copied to the _PublishedWebsites folder in the BuildAgent directory

Answer (score 0):

Possibility duplicate to  [Problems with MSBuild OutputPath and OutDir in TFS2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504202/problems-with-msbuild-outputpath-and-outdir-in-tfs2010) .

Also give a try wiht [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/publishedapplications), you can install it which will do this.

Answer (score 0):

With TFS 2012 build process template, you need to custom build process template to run the script after building, like the [post-build scripts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn376353%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) feature in TFS 2013 build process template.

You can refer to [this](http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/build-script-hooks-for-tfs-2012-builds) article to custom build process template to achieve your requirement.